# window.location.href not working, why not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I got some problems with window.location.href.
In my website I use AngularJS (framework).
I got a table with the following code:

```
<table id="MAND">

                <tbody id="hoveren">
                    <tr ng-repeat="artist in artists | filter:name">

                    <td class="user-name"><img id="{{artist.div}}" style="vertical-align: middle;" src="{{artist.img}}"></td>
                    <td class="user-email"  style="vertical-align: middle;">{{artist.name}}</td>
                    <td class="user-phone" style="vertical-align: middle;">{{artist.description}}</td>
                    <td class="user-phone"  style="vertical-align: middle;">{{artist.country}}</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

So you see the  gives the image a divname.

Then in jQuery, I call the following function:

```
$("#crunch").click(function() {
window.location.href = "http://example.com/new_url";
});
```

In this case, the {{"artist.div"}} was equal to crunch, so that's why #crunch.

Why isn't this working?

I click on it but nothing happens.

Is it some sort of stupid mistake anywhere?

Thanks!

Btw, if you want to know, my angularjs part:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('Controller', function($scope){
 $scope.artists = [
 {
  "name": "Crunchyroll",
  "country": "All countries except Japan",
  "img":"images/crunchy.png",
  "description":"You can set it to everything you want!", 
  "div":"crunch"
  },
  {
  "name": "Rhapsody",
  "country": "US only, be at the right spot",
  "img":"images/rhap.png",
  "description":"You can set it to everything you want!"
  },
  {
  "name": "Febreze",
  "country": "US only",
  "img":"images/feb.jpg",
  "description":"You can set it to everything you want!"
  },
  {
  "name": "Kellogs Froot Loops",
  "country": "US only",
  "img":"images/kel.jpg",
  "description":"You can set it to everything you want!"
  },
  {
  "name": "Pure Asia Garcinia Weight Loss",
  "country": "US, AU, CA, UK and NZ only",
  "img":"images/bottle.png",
  "description":"You can set it to everything you want!"
  },
  {
  "name": "Free Computer",
  "img":"images/pc.png",
  "description":"You can set it to everything you want!"
  },
  {
  "name": "whateveee",
  "country": "All countries except Japan",
  "img":"images/crunchy.png",
  "description":"You can set it to everything you want!", 
  "div":"crunch"
  }
 ];

});
```

Don't run btw, didn't know how to put it in.

Thanks!

Comment: Your jQuery code might be running before those divs are assigned that ID, so the event listener can't be attached to non-existent elements. I would highly suggest you try ng-click instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your code to following. At the time you are binding the event, there is no element with id #crunch in the html, hence, the binding never takes place.

So, for elements added dynamically, you need to bind events like following.

```
$(document).on('click', '#crunch', function(){
    window.location.href = "http://example.com/new_url";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work provided element with id `crunch` exists by the time  event handler is attached and it seems it doesn't. Use delegated events to solve this problem

```
$("#MAND").on('click', '#crunch', function() {
  window.location.href = "http://example.com/new_url";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery should really be a last resort here. Prefer Angular methods when they are available.

Inject `$window` into your controller:

```
.controller('Controller', function($scope, $window){
```

Add this function to your controller:

```
$scope.go = function(artist) {
  $window.location.href = "http://example.com";
};
```

Change your views to use `ng-click`:

```
<img id="{{artist.div}}" ng-click="go(artist)" ...
```

[Plunker demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uw8YaUaEcAKnDjSu5Mhc?p=preview)